# Google Assistant Timer + Action with One Command

Tags: google-home, samsung-smartthings, google-assistant, philips-hue, ifttt

I'm trying to figure out a clever way to set a Google Home timer and perform another action in one command.

I currently have a shortcut called "tea time" which sets a timer for my tea. I would really like to have it *also* trigger an IFTTT (or something) to make a light dim with it as a visual representation of the timer. I also have a smart things hub integrated. In the case of my light script, that's where the script actually runs.

Does anybody have any thoughts on how I could make that work so that I can run the timer *and* the light script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Assistant recently added the ability to execute multiple commands in a shortcut, which solves this problem for me. I was able change my "tea time" shortcut to look like:

> "Set a 4 minute timer called tea and turn on the 4 minute timer light."

Answer (score 3):

You could use the competitor *Stringify* which supports subsequent actions as well as conditions in their rule engine. [This rule](https://search.stringify.com/flows/9HedbvbkyB1MsqRHKewl) for example does three actions:

> WHEN I say "OK Google, tell Stringify Good Night"...
>
> THEN turn on my Hue Bulb A19 to orange at 15% brightness,
>   AND set the cool temperature on my Nest Thermostat to 69F...
>
> THEN fade off my Hue Bulb A19 over 10 minutes.

This seems very close to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Almost. But, I don't think there's a way I can set the GA timer with it.